# commit to svn unstages last commit?

Tags: git, svn, dcommit

Today i have encountered a weird problem when "dcommitting" my master HEAD to google code svn repository. Below an extract of what I did. I'd almost say that I do have uuid clash but i consider that to be unlikely. I'm getting more and more experienced with git but sometimes i'm still puzzled...

Some changes in my presentation branch...

```
jerry [~/dev/myproject]$git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
jerry [~/dev/myproject]$git merge presentation
Updating c5e5816..f5a376c
Fast-forward
 js/iPath.js        |    5 +----
 presentation/paper.html |    6 ++++--
 2 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

Changes are now in master

```
jerry [~/dev/myproject]$git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   presentation/.#paper.html
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Now I'm dcommitting to svn.

```
jerry [~/dev/myproject]$git svn fetch
jerry [~/dev/myproject]$git svn dcommit
Committing to https://myproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk ...
No changes
8e67cdc7e8bad816e402c1b9c72b5e84c492e907~1 == 8e67cdc7e8bad816e402c1b9c72b5e84c492e907
No changes between current HEAD and refs/remotes/trunk
Resetting to the latest refs/remotes/trunk
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   js/iPath.js
M   presentation/paper.html
Unable to extract revision information  from commit f5a376ca4a10a4807abbbea131b94b828ee88269~1
```

svn trunk is unmodified and my latest checkin (merge from presentation) is unstaged:

```
jerry [~/dev/project]$git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   js/iPath.js
#   modified:   presentation/paper.html
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   presentation/.#paper.html
```

Last commit is also removed from git log. What is going on?

Comment: `git svn rebase` did do some magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot `dcommit` "git-merges", because subversion does not have the same concept of merges as git (and any other dvcs: parent tracking) has. recent versions try to emulate it with `svn:merge-info` property, but it's not the same.

if you want to `dcommit` your dev branch changes to subversion, you have to rebase them first on master:

```
git rebase master dev
```

then you should be able to `dcommit`.

Comment: I learned this the hard way as well.  As good a job as git-svn does at insulating you from dealing with svn-isms, it can't do everything.  I found that using rebase is the more compatible choice when dealing with a subversion back-end.  There are a few question/answers on stackoverflow that I found particularly helpful.  I'll add links to those.